# UWP Binding a specific property of a hierachical object

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, datagrid, uwp-xaml

I want to access some values at the "root" of my main object (which is an object with a hierachical structure) inside some level of my datagrid that have another datacontext. At the moment it looks like this:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbe53.png)

As you can see on the screenshot with the textblocks above the grid I can access these properties outside, but in the grid I can't and I get a binding error.
The first level of my grid is binded with value1, the second with value2.

The errors for first level is:

```
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'TestValue' property not found on 'ProjectSolution.Core.Models.CaseTask'. BindingExpression: Path='TestValue' DataItem='ProjectSolution.Core.Models.CaseTask'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

I have the same error for the second level of my grid with the other property.

Here is the code I have simplified to highlight my problem:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="templateCell1" x:DataType="models:Case">
            <Grid x:Name="ItemCellGrid">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestValue}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="templateCell2" x:DataType="models:Case">
            <Grid x:Name="ItemCellGrid">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestValue2}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<controls:DataGrid 
           x:Name="dataGrid"
           ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SingleCase.CaseTasks}">
           <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                     <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Tasks" Binding="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
           </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
                                <Grid>
                                    <controls:DataGrid
                                        x:Name="rowDatagrid"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding CaseTasksDetails}">
                                        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Sub-Tasks" Binding="{Binding Name}"  FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                                            <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test" CellTemplate="{StaticResource templateCell2}" />
                                       </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                                   </controls:DataGrid>
                              </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                  <DataTemplate>
       </controls:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

My object:

```cs
public class Case
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public ObservableCollection<CaseTask> CaseTasks { get; set; }
     public string TestValue { get; set; }
     public string TestValue2 { get; set; }
     
     public Case()
     {
         CaseTasks = new ObservableCollection<CaseTask>();
         CaseTasks.Add(new CaseTask() { Name = "Level2_1" });
         CaseTasks.Add(new CaseTask() { Name = "Level2_2" });
         CaseTasks.Add(new CaseTask() { Name = "Level2_3" });
     }
 }
 public class CaseTask
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public ObservableCollection<CaseTaskDetail> CaseTasksDetails { get; set; }
     public CaseTask()
     {
         CaseTasksDetails = new ObservableCollection<CaseTaskDetail>();
         CaseTasksDetails.Add(new CaseTaskDetail() { Name = "Level3_1" });
         CaseTasksDetails.Add(new CaseTaskDetail() { Name = "Level3_2" });
         CaseTasksDetails.Add(new CaseTaskDetail() { Name = "Level3_3" });
     }
 }
 public class CaseTaskDetail
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

My viewmodel:

```cs
public class CaseDetailViewModel 
 {
     private Case _case;
     public Case SingleCase
     {
         get { return _case; }
         set {_case =value; }
     }
     public CaseDetailViewModel()
     {
         _case = new Case();
         _case.TestValue = "Value1";
         _case.TestValue2 = "Value2";
     }
```

Of course one of the simplest ways would be to propagate the properties in the child objects, but this would create a lot of redundancy in my data. I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the value of `TestValue2` which you want to access inside some level of the `DataGrid` as a static value of `MainPage`, and add [DataGrid.LoadingRowDetails event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.datagrid.loadingrowdetails?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) handler to change the value of `TestValue` based on the selected row in the first level of `DataGrid`. And you could show the value by a data binding with a [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter?view=winrt-19041), like this:

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public static string testString = "";
……
private void dataGrid_LoadingRowDetails(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
{
    int index = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
    testString = (index+2).ToString()+"th row: "+ ViewModel.SingleCase.TestValue2;
}
```

Converter class

```
public class DateFormatter : IValueConverter
{
    // This converts the DateTime object to the string to display.
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        return MainPage.testString;
    }

    // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding 
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:DateFormatter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    ……
</Page.Resources>

//Use the Converter in a column inside the second level of DataGrid
<controls:DataGridTextColumn  Width="120" Header="Test" Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```